# Doctrine2 insert fails silently, only on certain records

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following code which results sometimes in a silent failure:

```
public function updateCoreGameTableIfNecessary($coreEm)
{   
    $game = $this->getCoreGameRecord($coreEm);

    if (!$game) {

        $game = new Game();
        $game->setHomeSchool($this->getHomeSchool()->getCoreSchool($coreEm));
        $game->setDatetime($this->getDatetime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $game->setDate($this->getDatetime()->getTimestamp());
        $game->setTime($this->getDatetime()->format('H:i:s'));
        $game->setSport($coreEm->getRepository('VNNCoreBundle:Sport')->findOneByName($this->getSport()->getName()));
        $game->setSeason($coreEm->getRepository('VNNCoreBundle:Season')->findCurrent());
        $game->setEventType(strtolower($this->getEventType()->getName()));
        $game->setMeetName($this->getMeetName());
        $game->setRemoteUnique(md5(rand(0, 100000)));
        $game->setNotes($this->getRecap());
        $game->setHomeConfId(0); // This field is no longer used, so value doesn't matter.
        $game->setAwayConfId(0); // This field is no longer used, so value doesn't matter.
        $game->setConfStatus(''); // This field is going away as well.
    }   

    if ($this->getEventType()->getName() == 'Game') {
        $game->setHomeScore($this->getHomeScore());
        $game->setAwayScore($this->getAwayScore());
        $game->setAwaySchool($this->getAwaySchool()->getCoreSchool($coreEm));
    } else {
        $game->setPlace($this->getPlace());
        $game->setPoints($this->getHomeScore());
    }   

    $game->setOwnerId($this->getUser()->getSchool()->getCoreSchool($coreEm)->getId());
    $coreEm->persist($game);
    $coreEm->flush();

    return $game->getId();
}
```

It always starts with a `$this` that's already saved. For certain instances of `$this` (i.e. certain records in the database), `$game` won't get saved. I won't get an error or anything like that. It will just fail silently.

Any suggestions for debugging? I guess I'll try to figure out what's different about those certain records, but it seems like an insert should never silently fail, for any reason.

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting` set to report all errors?  Are these errors being logged or do you have display_errors set to show these on screen?

Comment: Yes. I've been notified of all other database errors. This failing insert doesn't seem to be throwing any.

Comment: Statements like these: 
$game->setSport($coreEm->getRepository('VNNCoreBundle:Sport')->findOneByName($this->getSport()->getName())); 

are dangerous. If no record is found (from the Sport repository) then you are calling a method (getName()) on a non-object. causing a Fatal error.

Comment: I would love a fatal error right now. What I'm getting is no error.

Comment: Possibly helpful: according to the MySQL query log, no query at all is being executed by my code. I don't know why, but I guess that's another piece of the puzzle.

Comment: If you're not seeing a query, that probably means that Doctrine's Unit of Work is for some reason deciding that it doesn't need to execute any statements for that object. That could mean that it thinks it already updated an instance of the same object, or there are no changes. You might want to debug the computeChangeSets() method of Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.